# R : break rows into combinations of pairs

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say I have the below lines and I want to break them into pairs:

```
  fname_c1 fname_c2 lname_c1 lname_c2    by    bm    bd group
  <fct>    <fct>    <fct>    <fct>    <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 STEFAN   NA       WOLFF    NA        1957     9     2     4
2 STEFAN   NA       MUELLER  NA        1957     6     7     4
3 STEFAN   NA       MUELLER  NA        1957     6     1     4
```

I'd like :

```
  fname_c1 fname_c2 lname_c1 lname_c2    by    bm    bd group
  <fct>    <fct>    <fct>    <fct>    <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 STEFAN   NA       WOLFF    NA        1957     9     2     4
2 STEFAN   NA       MUELLER  NA        1957     6     7     4

  fname_c1 fname_c2 lname_c1 lname_c2    by    bm    bd group
  <fct>    <fct>    <fct>    <fct>    <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 STEFAN   NA       WOLFF    NA        1957     9     2     4
3 STEFAN   NA       MUELLER  NA        1957     6     1     4

  fname_c1 fname_c2 lname_c1 lname_c2    by    bm    bd group
  <fct>    <fct>    <fct>    <fct>    <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
2 STEFAN   NA       MUELLER  NA        1957     6     7     4
3 STEFAN   NA       MUELLER  NA        1957     6     1     4
```

If I have 4 rows, I do `combn(4, 2)` and I get the combinations matrix.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4    3    4    4
```

But now how to I make the rows take the indices of the elements of the matrix :/ sorry I'm a bit of a dummy with matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`combn` can take a sequence of row index, and in the `FUN` we can subset the rows of the dataset based on the index

```
combn(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 2, FUN = function(i) df1[i,], simplify = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- mtcars[1:3, ]
```

Comment: awesome thanks. any chance this can be put in a for loop? The reason being, I need to add readline("message to user") after each pair

Comment: It returns a list.  Not clear which one should go in the loop

Comment: ok, i just put your answer in myList, and did a for loop for (i in myList){print(i)}
Thanks heaps @akrun